# How to turn off NodaTime when using EF Core to scaffold DbContext from Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, nuget, nodatime

In my Blazor Server app I'm using EF Core with Npgsql to database-first scaffold my DbContext and model classes. When I set it up, I followed the advice at [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html) and went with *NodaTime*. Which means I installed these NuGet packages:

- *Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL*
- *Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime*
- *Npgsql.NodaTime*

I would run this command for scaffolding:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold [connection-string-redacted] Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL ...
```

Now (*weeks later*) I've decided that *NodaTime* is overkill for *my specific situation*, even though I *fully appreciate why it exists and the multitude of problems it solves*. And I'd like to scaffold to .NET native types instead (aka *System.DateTime*).

So my first attempt was to comment out the line in Program.cs where I configure Npgsql to use NodaTime:

```
builder.Services
 .AddDbContextFactory<TheDbContext>(options =>
 {
      options.UseNpgsql(dbConnection, conf =>
      {
           //conf.UseNodaTime();
           conf.EnableRetryOnFailure();
           conf.CommandTimeout(2);
      });
 });
```

Running scaffolding after this change still generated NodaTime classes (*NodaTime.LocalDateTime*) for Postgres columns of type *timestamp*.

What do I need to do to get the cli scaffolding to stop using *NodaTime*?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the cli scaffolding does not care what is configured in Program.cs. It relies on the NuGet packages installed in the project.

And as long as *Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime* was still installed, scaffolding would use *NodaTime*.

Even though I did not explicitly specify it in the cli command (it just had *Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL*).

**The fix was to uninstall this NuGet Package from the project:**
*Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime*

Then scaffolding generated the desired .NET Native types (aka *System.DateTime*).